# Restore SQL Server database to rds failing

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm facing an issue with restoring a SQL Server `master.bak` file to my RDS instance running Microsoft SQL Server 2016 - v13.00.5820.21.v1 (X64) Express via S3. I am running the query below in SSMS

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database
          @restore_db_name='Master',
          @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::master/Master_backup_2021_09_01.bak';
```

The query runs but I get the following task_info message:

> Task execution has started. [ File 'D:\rdsdbdata\DATA\Master.mdf' is claimed by 'HC_Patient_Master_log'(2) and 'HC_Patient_Master'(1).
> The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

How do I use the `WITH MOVE` clause in my query? Is there any fix for this?

Please let me know for any questions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: AWS RDS won't allow you to restore a same-named database to the instance from which it was backed up. Ref: [Importing and exporting SQL Server databases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html), see: Limitations and recommendations. You could try alter-database-alter-file on the existing file+log, to rename the files, but I think you'll still hit this limitation.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for the comment! But this is not a same name database. It is a seperate master file. Any other ideas?

Comment: You can only have one database named `master` at a time, and that really should be the one installed with SQL Server itself. Given the names of the data and log files in your error message are you sure you shouldn't be restoring this database backup with the name `HC_Patient_Master` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning HC_Patient_Master is not a name of any database currently on the server.